# Повернуть 2D объект

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет. Возникла проблема, а именно. есть поинты, в которых лежат стрелки(пока что), как показано на рисунке.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написал такой метод, который должен поворачивать свою стрелку на минимальный по значению поинт.

```
private void LightningDirection(int id, GameObject searchedItem)
{
    Debug.Log("Откуда: " + PointsGO[id].name + "\nКуда: " + searchedItem.name);

    float angle = Vector3.SignedAngle(PointsGO[id].transform.position, searchedItem.transform.position, Vector2.right);

    Points[id].Lightning.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, 0f, angle);
}
```

После запуска, как уже можно было догадаться, стрелки повернуты неправильно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перепробовал много способов, но некоторые были еще хуже, а некоторые также работали неправильно. Вроде не сложная задача, но что-то остановила она меня.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Второй раз нахожу ответ на свой вопрос...

В общем нашел способ один, оставлю снизу, если кому нужен:

```
Vector3 difference = to.transform.position - from.transform.position;
float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotZ - 90, Vector3.forward);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, 1);
```

to - это объект на который вам надо смотреть.

> Примечание! Если у вас не ровно поворачивает объект(ы), то уберите из `rotZ - 90` вычитание 90 (просто чтобы rotZ был).

Comment: Если сами нашли ответ на свой вопрос  - отметьте его как правильный, чтобы закрыть вопрос

Comment: @vmchar через два дня можно поставить